# Search results from data api full of pirated music videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube data API. It's worrisome that a lot of the content my users are searching for is likely pirated material - in other words, music videos that probably don't have the artist's permission to be on YouTube.

I see YouTube has a 'YouTube music' URL, which looks to be approved by artists participating. I'm not sure if these results are taking precedence over others, or if they're even allowed to show up in third party search results. For example, if I search for:

> Bad Romance - Lady Gaga

will the 'official' music video appear in the results? How can we tell?

I'm thinking to shut off my service as a result of not being able to control this, I want to play fair,

Thanks

Comment: Why not let Google worry about the legality of the content?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted so heavily. It strikes me as a legit question - even if the answer is almost without a doubt, "We can't tell".

Comment: @pinkgothic It might get downvoted because it's not answerable, not programming related, better posed to YouTube, etc. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: @bzlm: See Colin Pickard's answer. That was my take on the question.

Comment: Yeah I guess the api will only show embed=allowed, syndicate=allowed if the video is really allowed to be used legitimately. There's no way to figure if a user is just uploading music videos themselves, the community would have to flag them for removal otherwise they'll go undetected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a programming question, I'm going to assume you mean "can I programatically determine Google's opinion of their agreement with the copyright holder?", I think the answer is no.  See for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4  - no music url or other indicator (that I can see), but I'd guess at 270m views it must have attracted sufficent attention for the copyright agreement status to be resolved.

So far as the rest of your question goes:

- "How can I tell if the owner of the artist has an agreement with Google which covers a specific video" - this is something to be answered by a court, not a programming question.  -
- The ethical question raised by co-operation with Google as a potential infringer of copyright is not a programming question either.

Comment: if by "youtube music" url you mean http://www.youtube.com/music then I would not assume that the copyright status of these are determined (especially looking at what is on there right now!).

Comment: Yeah what would be ideal is if I could restrict video searches only to content from youtube.com/music (if those are allowed to be embedded on third party sites in the first place). Then I could have some ethical peace knowing that I'm showing video content that was approved by the artists (or at least their record labels). No way to do that right now though I think?

Comment: Hi, do you know if the situation is still the same? Any news about it?